# No access to Google private cluster via master authorized networks

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, gke-networking

The current setup I have:

```
Google Project "Test Project"
  VPC "test-vpc01"
  Subnet "test-vpc01-sub01"
    Subnet Range "10.3.1.0/24"
    Private Cluster "test-cluster"
      Master address range "10.4.1.0/28"
      Master authorized networks "10.6.1.0/28"
      Master zone "europe-west2-b"
  Subnet "test-vpc01-sub02"
    Subnet Range "10.6.1.0/24"
    Compute VM "test-vm"
      Zone "europe-west2-b"
      Internal IP "10.6.1.2"
```

When I try to commit a "kubectl" command I receive the following:

```
user@test-vm:~/.kube$ kubectl get pods -v 10
I0227 15:17:59.446195    1153 loader.go:359] Config loaded from file /home/tristan_clarke/.kube/config
I0227 15:17:59.447194    1153 loader.go:359] Config loaded from file /home/tristan_clarke/.kube/config
I0227 15:17:59.447982    1153 round_trippers.go:419] curl -k -v -XGET  -H "Accept: application/json, */*" -H "User-Agent: kubectl/v1.13.3 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/721bfa7" 'https://10.4.1.2/api?timeout=32s'
I0227 15:18:29.450476    1153 round_trippers.go:438] GET https://10.4.1.2/api?timeout=32s  in 30002 milliseconds
I0227 15:18:29.450502    1153 round_trippers.go:444] Response Headers:
I0227 15:18:29.450540    1153 cached_discovery.go:113] skipped caching discovery info due to Get https://10.4.1.2/api?timeout=32s: dial tcp 10.4.1.2:443: i/o timeout
```

Google documentation just informs to ensure the CIDR address is correct. Although, I'm certain that's not the issue wondering if it is possibly firewall rules/routing etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not able to connect to a private cluster with a private endpoint from outside your vpc.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a firewall rule automatically created to allow traffic.
You can check the firewall rules using the next command:

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules list
```

If there is no firewall rule, you can create one manually using the the next command:

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules create <<NAME>> --allow all \
      --description "Allow incoming traffic" \
      --destination-ranges <<CIDR-RANGE>> \
      --destination-ranges <<CIDR-RANGE>> \
      --direction INGRESS
```

I wish that this can help you. :)

Comment: I have indeed made sure the firewall rules are in place. I have the following rules.

Comment: @TristanC your comment don't have the firewall rules. Can you add them so I can try to help you?

Comment: This issue has now been resolved. The problem was that I was using a different vpc to connect to the private cluster. You can only connect to private clusters from within that same vpc.